# Set category when posting blog to Umbraco with Microsoft Word

Tags: c#, post, ms-word, umbraco, blogs

I created an Umbraco blog with posts in Microsoft Word, but I configured the channel with fields for content and for categories.

When I go to Word and add a category it's empty, Word doesn't read the categories existing in Umbraco. Why not?

How to configure Microsoft Word to load Umbraco existing tags?

[image: Image for word categories combobox]

Comment: You can post blogs from Microsoft Word to Umbraco? How?

Comment: I use the umbraco user channel to configure a document type what will receive the title, description and tags, than i connect on word with my umbraco user credentials and its work, i follow this tutorial https://www.eyecatch.no/blog/using-word-2007-2010-with-umbraco/

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the data only goes in one direction - from Word to Umbraco, not the other way around.

Therefore, Word cannot know what values have been set in Umbraco.